# Circumvent Plugin redirect

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I am dealing with a WP plugin, which redirects users from example.com to example.com/?lang=de using 302.

Its hard to find where this redirect is exaclty located in the code.

What I need to do is, is to implement my own redirect from example.com and www.example.com to /?lang=de using 301.

However, when I implement a redirect like this in htaccess:

```
Redirect / /?lang=de
```

I get a browser error saying "too many redirects".

I also tried rewriting www to non www, but then no URL except the homepage URL works.

What can I do here?

Comment: Are you using any plugins? Like "yoast". Deactivate all plugins and then check.

Comment: thx but this plugin is necessary. I need to like override it.